# What does justify the use of coroutines instead of subroutines?

Tags: coroutine, rules, subroutine

I am currently exploring coroutines in Python, but I have difficulties in determining when to use them over normal subroutines. I am trying to explain my problem with the help of an example.

The task is to iterate over tabular data and format the content of the row according to its entry in the `type` field. When formatted, the result is written to the same output file.

```
index | type | time | content
-----------------------------
0     | A    | 4    | ...
1     | B    | 6    | ...
2     | C    | 9    | ...
3     | B    | 11   | ...
...
```

Normally, I would check the type and write some sort of switch case and delegate the data to a specific subroutine (== function) like so (pseudo-code):

```
outfile = open('test.txt')

for row in infile:

    switch(row.type)
    {
    case A:
        format_a(row.content, outfile)    // subroutine that formats and writes data of type A
        break

    case B:
        format_b(row.content, outfile)    // same for type B...
        break

    case C:
        format_c(row.content, outfile)    // ... and type C
        break

    default:
        // handle unknown type exception
        break
    }

close(outfile)
```

The question is: would I get any benefit from realizing this with coroutines? I don't think so, and let me explain why: if I have determined the type of a row, I would pass the content to the respective coroutine. As long as I do this, the other coroutines and the calling function are paused. The data is formatted and written to the file and passes control back to the calling function which gets the next row, etc. This procedure repeats until I run out of rows. Therefore, this is exactly what the workflow using subroutines would look like.

One pro for using coroutines here would be if I had to keep track of some state. Maybe I am interested in the time difference to the last row per type. In this case, the coroutine function for B would save the time of its first call (6). When it is called the second time, it retrieves the value (11) and can calculate the difference (11 - 6 = 5). This would be way harder to do with subroutines.

But is the argument of keeping track of some state the only reason for using coroutines? I am looking for a rule-of-thumb, not a rule that covers every case possible.